# Not able to scp files. Possibly a syntax mistake?

Tags: windows, scp, file-copy

I am trying to use an SSH connection to connect from a Windows PC to a remote Ubuntu.

I tried copying a file from the remote machine, being in the relevant file directory like such:

```
scp filename C:\Documents\filename
```

I get the message:

```
could not resolve host name c
```

So I think I'm missing a prefix to my PC path, but I have no idea what it is.

How can I solve it?

Comment: For transferring between Linux and Windows, it would be easier to use a Windows client such as WinSCP

Comment: Where did you get the `scp` command from (what system or package did you install it from)?

Answer (score 1):

Various examples for `scp` format can be found [here](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php)

In order to copy from a remote Ubuntu machine into your local machine it should be something like:

```
scp username@hostname:/full/path/to/remote_file local_filename
```

- **filename**   - the full-path+filename of the file in the local system
- **username**   - the user-name on the remote system
- **hostname**   - the host-name (or IP address) of the remote system
- **/full/path** - the full path of the destination location of the file

The error you got, specify that `scp` expect `C` to be the host name (as it is before the `:`) and `scp` didn't manage to locate hostname `C`.

If you execute the `scp` command from the Ubuntu machine and want to copy a file from it to a remote Windows machine the `scp` format should be:

```
scp local_filename username@hostname:/full/path/to/remote_file
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, if I understand you answer correctly, you reversed the situation to copying from local to remote. But I am now more confused. Why would I need username and hostname if I am in an active SSH shell, in the directory where the file I need is located? and is C:\Documents\filename the full path at my local PC or am I missing something before the C?

Comment: @Ytry - what exactly would you like to do? is your local computer ubuntu? would you like to copy from the remote Windows machine into the locale Ubuntu machine?

Comment: My local is Windows, the remote is Ubuntu. I would like to copy from the remote to the local

Comment: @Ytry - I've updated my answer to show how to copy from remote Ubuntu server into local machine - assuming that you have `scp` installed in your windows as a command line, (e.g. Windows10 bash or git bash)

Comment: @Ytry - take a look at the link to the `scp` examples in my answer

Comment: You are saying to use scp from a cmd window? not from within the ssh shell connection?

Comment: From/To which machine did you `ssh`?

Comment: I am on my local windows. Connected via ssh to a remote Ubuntu, in the directory where the file is. I want to copy this file from this location to my local.

Comment: Maybe scp is not what I need?

Comment: edited my answer: If you are logged in to the Ubuntu, the command should be: `scp Ubuntu_local_filename username@windows_hostname:/full/path/to/remote_file`

Comment: So now I have:  windows_username@windows_hostname:C\Documents.... and I still get: "could not resolve host name windows_hostname.

Comment: @Ytry - replace *windows_hostname* with its IP address

Comment: @Ytry - how did you `ssh` from your windows to Ubuntu? which ssh client did you use?

Comment: I have found the answer to my problem. You cannot scp from within an ssh shell. Thanks for your efforts all the same!